# Box2d body sticks to side of platforms/walls while applying impulse

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Working on a sidescrolling platform type game and running into a weird issue with my character.  If he moves into the side of a platform and I continue to hold the movement button he just sticks to it and doesnt fall until I let up the movement key.  Here is my movement code:

```
public void move(float percent){
        float desiredVel = speed.x *percent;
        float velChange = desiredVel - b2body.getLinearVelocity().x;
        float impulse = b2body.getMass() * velChange;
        b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(impulse,0),b2body.getWorldCenter(),true);
    }
```

This is called given a percent based on a touchpad controller, but basically percent is somewhere between -1 and 1.  This is my body/fixture for the character:

```
BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        bdef.position.set(704/ Constants.PPM, 1000/Constants.PPM);
        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        b2body = world.createBody(bdef);
        b2body.setFixedRotation(true);

        //Hitbox
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(20/Constants.PPM,45/Constants.PPM);
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        //Add in category and mask bits
        hitbox = b2body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        hitbox.setUserData("hitbox");
```

And this is the body/fixture for the platforms:

```
bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bdef.position.set((rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2) / Constants.PPM, (rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2) / Constants.PPM);

            body = world.createBody(bdef);

            shape.set(new Vector2(-rect.getWidth()/2/Constants.PPM, rect.getHeight()/2/Constants.PPM),new Vector2(rect.getWidth()/2/Constants.PPM, rect.getHeight()/2/Constants.PPM));

            fdef.shape = shape;
            fdef.friction = 0.5f;
            fdef.density = 1;
            fdef.filter.categoryBits = Constants.GROUND_BIT;
            body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("platform");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the friction generated by the player pushing into the platform which overcomes gravity.

A few things you could try:

1. Reduce the friction of the character or platforms to reduce friction.
2. Add a sensor to detect when these friction collisions are happening and disable the user input for that direction.
3. Add friction free bodies on sides of platforms or sides of player